# type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: string, flutter, timestamp

I am getting the above error on the date of birth, although i convert it to string and in the firestore it is registered as a string. the code for registration of the user:

```
String dateOfBirth = DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 11);
DateTime selected;

CustomCard(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: ListTile(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 30),
                  onTap: () => pickDate(viewModel),
                  title: Text(
                    '$dateOfBirth',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                  ),
                  focusNode: viewModel.dobFN,
                  trailing: Icon(
                    iconReflection,
                    size: 25,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
```

picking the date:

```
Future pickDate(RegisterViewModel viewModel) async {
selected = await showDatePicker(
  initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.year,
  context: context,
  initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: new DateTime(1930),
  lastDate: new DateTime(2022),
);
setState(() {
  if (selected != null && !selected.isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
    dateOfBirth = selected.toString().substring(0, 10);
    iconReflection = Icons.check;
    viewModel.setDOB(dateOfBirth);
  } else {
    iconReflection = Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle;
  }
});
}
```

viewModel code:

```
setDOB(String dateOfBirth) {
dob = dateOfBirth;
notifyListeners();
}
```

in the userModel it set as a string as well. So where is the TimeStamp hiding?

```
class UserModel {
String username, email, photoUrl, id, phone, sex, dob;

UserModel({this.username, this.email, this.id, this.photoUrl, this.phone, 
this.sex, this.dob});
```

thank you!

Comment: What is the type of dob?

Comment: dob is a string.

Comment: Please share a screenshot or log to get the better understanding on the issue

Comment: I have a search list populated with the users fetched from the firebase. It builds from the users.fromJson. the app displayes that error in the search class only. i will edit my question later. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> So where is the TimeStamp hiding?

Timestamp likely means a unix timestamp here. It seems that somewhere you are giving a date object where you should be giving a string. i can't find the problem from your code though.

Comment: the only instance with the date i have is to check when was the user last seen. other than that nothing... thanks anyways, will have to go through the whole thing again.